# Ajax XHR returns 500 error, but the PHP file works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

index.html (returns 500 error when running this ajax request)

```js
function checkUnread(username) {
  $.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.projecttranslation.org/cvlgbt/www/web/unreadcount.php",
    data: { user: username },
    cache: true,
    success: function ( data ) {
      alert(data);
    }
  })
}
```

unreadcount.php (works fine when run by itself)

```php
<?php

header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 

$link = new mysqli(BLOCKED FOR SECURITY REASONS);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "1";

$result->close();

$link->close();
```

Obviously I removed some integral pieces of code for debugging and security purposes, but here is what I'm trying to do:

When the user logs in, I want checkUnread() to check the database for unread messages, count how many there are, and then return that number via the Ajax XHR. Once Ajax has the result, it then dynamically injects it into the bottom toolbar style jQuery Mobile menu to show an "Unread Count" such as "Mail [2]". If that makes sense...any thoughts why this would be returning a 500 error?

Comment: Check your server logs for whatever messages the server logged there that indicate what internal server failure caused it to send that 500 response.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find something like that in cPanel. I looked in File Manager and found a log but it didn't really tell me much, nothing that would lead me to the answer.

Comment: @MatthewWalker what is the log about?

Comment: it shows info like this:
`Sun Sep 30 21:28:27 2018 0 71.95.86.119 726 /home/prjtrans/public_html/cvlgbt/www/index.js a _ i r redphyre@projecttranslation.org ftp 1 * c
Sun Sep 30 21:28:50 2018 0 71.95.86.119 16502 /home/prjtrans/public_html/cvlgbt/www/index.php a _ i r redphyre@projecttranslation.org ftp 1 * c`

Comment: In this case the return result of the XHR is 500 internal error in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited your link, but got status code 500 in console.
And I notice that you use an undeined var `$result` in your code

```
$result->close();
```

I doubt taht this code is the reason. If I am wrong, please check your error log configured in you php-fpm.conf and post it out

Comment: I take that back, that was the problem, the variable I forgot to remove. Thanks for pointing out something so simple to me it wasn't obvious at all. I always miss the small things. lol